# Can imacros clear ALL history, cache and cookies

Tags: cookies, imacros

Is there a way to clear all cache and cookies (equivalent of pressing `ctrl`+`shift`+`del` in firefox and selecting every checkbox) using imacros?

I know about the `CLEAR` command but I have found that it doesn't clear everything. Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't it clear? I used it and it cleared a lot of stuff. Don't know any other cleaning method. Maybe something in Firefox or JS.

Comment: @macroscripts I am not exactly sure what doesn't it clear but outlook manages to recognize my computer although I changed the ip and cleared cookies through imacros. That doesn't happen when I clear cookies and all history manually.

Comment: i think this needs to be moved to other site possible super user http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ***CLEAR*** command so that times of website response measurements are not influenced by using local cache data:

Answer (score 0):

The code "CLEAR" without quote actually deletes all content. Make sure you do not run this function in incognito mode. This is because incognito do not delete content in as much as it doesn't save. But some sites can still pick your data on incognito mode. To make your script clear all data, run the script in a normal mode.