# How to clear all cache of IMacro Browser?

Tags: vba, caching, browser-cache, imacros

I am using IMacro browser. It uses Internet Explorer browser. It looks like it uses some parameters from caching data.

I want to clear the cache. For that, I have tried to clear cache of Internet Explorer browser but it doesn't reflect on IMacro browser. IMacro browser still uses parameters of cached data.

I have read some reference

1- [Can imacros clear ALL history, cache and cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434682/can-imacros-clear-all-history-cache-and-cookies)

2- http://wiki.imacros.net/CLEAR

3- http://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=24378

But I don't know where to fire `CLEAR` command.

Do I need to fire in MS Excel VBA code where I use this?

Or

Do I need to fire somewhere in IMacro windows of application?

[image]